# Why doesn't South Korea have a tax treaty with the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, south-korea

https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z

> **The United States has tax treaties with a number of foreign countries.
> Under these treaties, residents (not necessarily citizens) of foreign
> countries are taxed at a reduced rate, or are exempt from U.S. taxes
> on certain items of income they receive from sources within the United
> States.** These reduced rates and exemptions vary among countries and
> specific items of income. Under these same treaties, residents or
> citizens of the United States are taxed at a reduced rate, or are
> exempt from foreign taxes, on certain items of income they receive
> from sources within foreign countries. Most income tax treaties
> contain what is known as a "saving clause" which prevents a citizen or
> resident of the United States from using the provisions of a tax
> treaty in order to avoid taxation of U.S. source income.

Why doesn't South Korea have a tax treaty with the United States? South Korea being an ally of the U.S. like Japan, which has a tax treaty with the U.S., you would think South Korea has one with the U.S. too, but I was wondering why not and whether South Korea has oFficially given a reason for why they decided to not have one with the U.S.